# Let /m/[number] link between Main and Meta

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, short-links

### Proposal

- `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/m/1473` should link to [Meta.Judaism.SE post #1473](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473).
- `http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/m/1473` should link to [Judaism.SE post #1473](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473).

And, of course, likewise for other Stack Exchange sites. This would be done via an HTTP 301 redirect, as the `/u/1473`, `/q/1473`, and `/a/1473` URLs are already.

(If one of those directions — a short URL from Main to Meta or vice versa — is deemed a Bad Thing, then just do the other. Perhaps link `/m/1473` to Meta post #1473 whether the link is from Main or from Meta.)

### Rationale

- **Why a short URL:** People frequently want to link in comments on Main to Meta posts and vice versa. This will allow a briefer way to do so. Brevity in comments is important, because

  - there's a strict character limit and

    the markdown of a comment is more human-readable if its embedded URL is shorter.

  Compare `[foo](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473)` to `[foo](/m/1473)`.
- **Why *this* short URL:** This is familiar notation: people know the `/u/1473` shortcut to user #1473 and the `/q/1473` and `/a/1473` shortcuts to post #1473 on the same site. So there's little learning curve. And the `m` alludes to "meta".

Comment: I think clarity and a lack of surprises in URLs is more important than brevity/convenience here.

Comment: @AnnaLear, the `m` alludes to "meta". I'll edit the question.

Comment: Sure, while you're on main. When you're on meta, the `m` now means something completely different.

Comment: @AnnaLear, yeah, "main". It works. `:-)` (Actually, I've seen the non-meta sites referred to as "main", but I don't know that's popular across all the per-site metas. If not, then the `m` will be opaque on some sites.) (As an alternative, this short URL can work only from Main to Meta (or vice versa). I'm editing....)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm making my point clearly enough. :) The shortcut's meaning changes in a way that's not immediately obvious or discoverable. That's a bad thing.

Comment: @AnnaLear, yeah, I've edited. But note that the meaning stays "link to the associated site" if it links from Main to Meta and from Meta to Main.

Comment: I'd hesitantly support this, but only where /m/ means meta. Doesn't make much sense for links to main, those won't ever be shorter with this syntax.

Comment: @Undo, maybe post an answer so people can upvote that more-specific proposal and downvote mine if they so desire. (But links to main will be shorter with this syntax: `(/m/1473)` is shorter than `(//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473)`.)

Comment: Note the implications of changing links if a question is migrated from main to meta.  This could be surprising to people clicking the link.

Comment: I've upvoted this post because I support the general idea, but I prefer the variation suggested in [Monica Cellio's answer].

Comment: Thanks for migrating this to MSE! I've wondered many times why don't have such shortcuts.

Comment: This might confuse people since adding an `m` can also indicate medium or mobile.

Answer (score 22):

I like having a shorthand for moving between main and meta in comments.  As noted in the question, "m/q/613" consumes much less of the limited resources of a comment than the full URL.

However, having the URL be context-sensitive makes me uncomfortable.  While yes, *relative* URLs are always context-sensitive, this feels like overloading that will confuse users.  I therefore propose shorthands `main/` and `meta/`.  Yes it's 3 more characters, but it's completely unambiguous (and still shorter than the full URL).  Further, these could reasonably work from chat, while the proposed context-sensitive `m/` couldn't.  (I'm not saying we want to explicitly support them in chat, but sometimes people will onebox a comment into chat, so if this change makes it more likely that someone clicking on the link wouldn't get the wrong results, that's a win.)

Comment: Shortcuts like these would be semantically very clear in any context. For example, that `foo.stackexchange.com/meta/1473` and `meta.foo.stackexchange.com/meta/1473` both point to `meta.foo.stackexchange.com/questions/1473` makes a great deal of sense to me, and it's obvious from reading any of these URLs, in or out of context, what they're intended to point to.